# What is the reason for the error in verifying if a date is within a period when the date is the first day of the month?

Tags: javascript

I try to identify if a date is between the periods of today, the current week or the current month, for this purpose I have written the functions `getBorderDates` and`isDateInPeriod` to first obtain the initial and final dates in a period and then verify if a given date is between that period

I have been testing and I have found errors when the date to be verified corresponds to the first day of the month, apparently when checking with other dates it returns correct results

I thank you in advance for your observations

```js
const TODAY = "TODAY";
const CURRENT_WEEK = "CURRENT_WEEK";
const CURRENT_MONTH = "CURRENT_MONTH";

const getBorderDates = period => {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  let from = undefined;
  let until = undefined;

  if (period === TODAY) {
    const today = new Date();

    from = new Date(today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
    until = new Date(today.setHours(24, 0, 0, 0));
  }

  if (period === CURRENT_WEEK) {
    const first = currentDate.getDate() - currentDate.getDay();
    const last = first + 6;

    from = new Date(currentDate.setDate(first));
    until = new Date(currentDate.setDate(last));
  }

  if (period === CURRENT_MONTH) {
    from = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), 1);
    until = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth() + 1, 0);
  }

  return [from, until];
};

const isDateInPeriod = ({ date, period }) => {
  const [from, until] = getBorderDates(period);
  const timestamp = new Date(date).getTime();

  return timestamp >= from.getTime() && timestamp <= until.getTime();
};


console.log("When is the date of the first day of the month fails")
console.log(isDateInPeriod({ date: "2020-03-01", period: TODAY }));
console.log(isDateInPeriod({ date: "2020-03-01", period: CURRENT_WEEK }));
console.log(isDateInPeriod({ date: "2020-03-01", period: CURRENT_MONTH }));

console.log("When is another date, is it correct")
console.log(isDateInPeriod({ date: "2020-03-01", period: TODAY }));
console.log(isDateInPeriod({ date: "2020-03-02", period: CURRENT_WEEK }));
console.log(isDateInPeriod({ date: "2020-03-05", period: CURRENT_MONTH }));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
const first = currentDate.getDate() - currentDate.getDay();
const last = first + 6;

from = new Date(currentDate.setDate(first));
until = new Date(currentDate.setDate(last));
```

the hours in `from` are as in `currentDate` and not 00:00. This means that when you compare against today, 00:00, you get unexpected results. Set the hours of `from` to midnight and it will work:

```
from = new Date(currentDate.setDate(first));
from.setHours(0, 0, 0);
```

```js
const TODAY = "TODAY";
const CURRENT_WEEK = "CURRENT_WEEK";
const CURRENT_MONTH = "CURRENT_MONTH";

const getBorderDates = period => {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  let from = undefined;
  let until = undefined;

  if (period === TODAY) {
    const today = new Date();

    from = new Date(today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
    until = new Date(today.setHours(24, 0, 0, 0));
  }

  if (period === CURRENT_WEEK) {
    const first = currentDate.getDate() - currentDate.getDay();
    const last = first + 6;

    from = new Date(currentDate.setDate(first));
    from.setHours(0, 0, 0); // MODIFY HERE
    until = new Date(currentDate.setDate(last));
  }

  if (period === CURRENT_MONTH) {
    from = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), 1);
    until = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth() + 1, 0);
  }

  return [from, until];
};

const isDateInPeriod = ({ date, period }) => {
  const [from, until] = getBorderDates(period);
  const timestamp = new Date(date).getTime();

  return timestamp >= from.getTime() && timestamp <= until.getTime();
};


console.log("When is the date of the first day of the month fails")
console.log(isDateInPeriod({ date: "2020-03-01", period: TODAY }));
console.log(isDateInPeriod({ date: "2020-03-01", period: CURRENT_WEEK }));
console.log(isDateInPeriod({ date: "2020-03-01", period: CURRENT_MONTH }));

console.log("When is another date, is it correct")
console.log(isDateInPeriod({ date: "2020-03-01", period: TODAY }));
console.log(isDateInPeriod({ date: "2020-03-02", period: CURRENT_WEEK }));
console.log(isDateInPeriod({ date: "2020-03-05", period: CURRENT_MONTH }));
```

Comment: I probably misunderstood your answer, but in the case of the date 2020-03-01 which is my local date in any of the periods it returns me false

Comment: Interesting. For me All the logs say "true", while jn your question I get 'false' for the week period.